# How to use Get and Set with stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've been using SQL Server 2008 and C# for some time but have always struggled with OOP side of it. I normally write my `Insert` statements as follows. The following excerpt is an AJAX Website that I'm playing around with

```
SqlCommand scCommand = new SqlCommand("spLocationsCreate", APMConn);
scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

scCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocationCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = txtLocationCode.Text;
scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtLocation.Text;

scCommand.Connection.Open();
scCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
scCommand.Connection.Close();
```

The above works and adds a record to the database, I thought I'd start to use the above with classes - Set and Get. Have written the following class

```
public class clsLocations
{
    public clsLocations()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    private string _LocationCode;
    private string _Locations;

    public string LocationCode
    {
        get { return _LocationCode; }
        set { _LocationCode = value; }
    }

    public string Locations
    {
        get { return _Locations; }
        set { _Locations = value; }
    }
}
```

I understand the above but am struggling on how to use it with a stored procedure and how to call it. I've read many articles on the net but many use direct SQL as opposed to stored procedures and parameters

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to have a Save() method on your clsLocations class, which calls the stored proc and populates the parameters accordingly. E.g:

```
public void Save(SqlConnection apmConn)
{
    SqlCommand scCommand = new SqlCommand("spLocationsCreate", apmConn);
        scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocationCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = this.LocationCode;
        scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = this.Locations;
        scCommand.Connection.Open();
        scCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        scCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

For future investigation, you may want to think about separating out the database code from your model classes.  You could use an ORM such as EntityFramework. Or a simple data access layer consisting of static functions for calling your stored procedures.

Comment: Edit to add (untested) example

Comment: I understand what you have written above but how does it know that txtLocationCode is this.LocationCode

Comment: Apologies I missed that bit.  So, you would either have a button on your form that when clicked creates a new instance of clsLocations and sets it's properties from the form.  Or you would add calls to Save() in the setters so that when they change it saves automatically, but watch out for performance if you follow that path.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I copied your code above into my class, can you write the full code on the best way to achieve this.

The way I initially wrote it at the top is shorter and it works fine but everyone seems to be writing it using classes today generating more code than is necessary. I don't see the point of it

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Think I've cracked it.....this works but please advise if I'm doing something wrong

Have got my Class which is right at the top and added this beneath the code

```
public void SaveLocation(SqlConnection APMConn)
{
    SqlCommand scCommand = new SqlCommand("spLocationsCreate", APMConn);
    scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocationCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = _LocationCode;
    scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = _Locations;
    scCommand.Connection.Open();
    scCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    scCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

In my main program have the following

```
protected void InsertNewLocations(SqlConnection conn)
{
    clsLocations NewLoc = new clsLocations();
    NewLoc.LocationCode = txtLocationCode.Text;
    NewLoc.Locations = txtLocation.Text;
    NewLoc.SaveLocation(APMConn); 
}
```